# How to solve this indefinite integral of a sine curve?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am carrying out through my report but I got into a part with integration that I don’t know how to solve because I am still a beginner on integration.
$$
\int-0.807 \sin \left(\frac{π}{12}  t\right) e^{0.269} dt
$$

Comment: Note that $-0.807$ and $e^{0.269}$ are just constants. So essentially you're just integrating the $\sin$-part. Do you know how to integrate
$$
\int \sin kx\, dx
$$ for a constant $k$ ?

Comment: Oh ok because to be honest we just started integration two days ago in class.

Comment: Do you mind solving it please

Comment: Congratulations on starting to study calculus :) So onto the question itself, I'll give you a hint: If you know how to integrate a simple function $f(x)$ (without the scaling factor $k$), then
$$
\int f(kx) \, dx = \frac{1}{k} \int k f(kx) \, dx
$$
And now you have to remember how the composition of two function is **differentiated** ... Do you know how to differentiate something like $f(g(x))$ ?

Comment: Consult a table of integrals, this is a fairly standard result so should be on there

Comment: I have no clue what I should do to be honest

Comment: Take the constants out of the integral and integrate $\sin( \frac{\pi}{12} t)$. By any chance, are you doing IB (International Baccalaureate)?

Comment: Yes I am doing IB

Comment: Your best bet is to ask your teacher. You shouldn't put anything in your IA that you do not understand yourself. If you rely on the answers on this site for the main part of your working, you will likely get marked down for Criterion E: use of mathematics.

Comment: Yes I have thought about that which is the scary part. This is also the reason when I ask questions here is ask for the fully detailed procedure to make me understand first before putting it in my IA. I have one question that you know IB, do you think using the same mathematical procedure as a certain website would be fine? (With the citation of course?)

Comment: Yep, that would be fine. It's good to know that you're trying to understand the concepts before putting them into your IA. Best of luck learning calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small trick to be used in this case. First, we have to review a bit of differentiation.

If we have a function $f(x)$ and we know its derivative $f'(x)$, then a "scaled" version of $f(x)$ is differentiated like so
$$ \tag{1}
\frac{d}{dx}f(kx) = kf'(kx)
$$
This is an important result to learn and know, before learning integration.

---

So back to the question itself. We have the following integral (I'll remove the constants):
$$
\int \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{12}t \right)\, dt
$$
How would we solve this? We certainly know that $\int \sin t \, dt = -\cos t +C$, but how do we deal with the factor $\frac{\pi}{12}$ ? Well, we can modify the expression a bit:
$$
\int \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{12}t \right)\, dt = \frac{12}{\pi} \int \frac{\pi}{12} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{12} t \right) \, dt
$$
I have done nothing else than to multiply and divide by the same constant. Please convince yourself that this is true. But how does this help us? Well, looking at the integral now, we see that
$$
\int \underbrace{ \frac{\pi}{12} \cdot \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{12} t \right)}_{\text{this}} \, dt
$$
reminds of the thing that we learned from differentiation! It looks like the right-hand side of Equation (1). Perhaps it could be that $k = \frac{\pi}{12}$ and $f'(kt) = \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{12} t \right)$... Since integration is the reverse operation of differentiation, we only need to figure out what function $f(x)$ would have this feature. In other words
$$
\int k f'(kt) \, dt = f(kt) + C
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes I think I can. I also asked my teacher about. Thanks a lot @Matti P.

Comment: Hello again, I tried figuring it out and I got , 0.807e^0.269 cos (πt/12) +C then whole thing divided by (π/12)

Comment: Is this right @Matti P.

Comment: Yes you are correct! Happy holidays :)

Comment: Sounds good thanks a lot for your help @Matti P.